# Can't get close button to work on modal box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use a list element to open a modal box, but for some reason the close button is not working, I would also appreciate some advice general advice on my current work. I was following the W3 tutorial for modal box.

The whole HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="bg"></div>
<div class="bg bg2"></div>
<div class="bg bg3"></div>
</div>
  <section class="showcase">
    <header>
      <h1 class="name noselect">Some dude</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="text">
      <h2>Some dude</h2> 
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="social">
      <li ><a href="#" id="myBtn">About</a>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text in the Modal.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt commodi est deleniti cum distinctio minima dolore impedit eius, adipisci ea tenetur obcaecati iusto, dolorem, quaerat magni eaque rerum amet tempora!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    
    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    
    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; 
}

body{
  animation-name: backgroundColorPalette;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: linear; 
}
html {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}

.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
     -khtml-user-select: none; 
       -moz-user-select: none; 
        -ms-user-select: none; 
            user-select: none; 
}
.bg {
  animation:slide 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, rgb(81, 128, 116) 50%, rgb(142, 100, 190) 50%);
  bottom:0;
  left:-50%;
  opacity:.5;
  position:fixed;
  right:-50%;
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
}

.bg2 {
  animation-direction:alternate-reverse;
  animation-duration:4s;
}

.bg3 {
  animation-duration:5s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform:translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateX(25%);
  }
}
header
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header .name
{
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 5em;
}


.showcase
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}
.showcase.active
{
  right: 300px;
}

.text
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text h2
{
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.text h3
{
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.text p
{
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  max-width: 700px;
}
.social
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
.social li a
{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2em;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #111;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.social li
{
  list-style: none;
}
.text a:hover
{
  letter-spacing: 6px;
}
.social li a:hover
{
  transform: scale(0.8) translateY(-15px);
}
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  
@media (max-width: 991px)
{
  .name h1{
    font-size: 6em;
  }

  .overlay {
    height: 5%;
  }

  .showcase,
  .showcase header
  {
    padding: 40px;
  }
  .text h2
  {
    font-size: 5em;
  }
  .text h3
  {
    font-size: 4em;
  }
  .text p
  {
    font-size: 3em;
  }  
  
  .social, 
  .social li, 
  .social li a
  {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 2px;
  }
}
```

And for some reason, if I try to the following, the close button do work.

```
<body>
  <div class="bg"></div>
<div class="bg bg2"></div>
<div class="bg bg3"></div>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
  <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    
    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    
    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems the x button works?

Comment: It works just on the second example but not in the second one, for the first example I can close it by clicking on anything but the x button.

Comment: On my end close button x works. But seems `header` tag blocks the x button.

Comment: I added an answer so check it out.

Comment: It does, thank you, do you know how I can keep it without blocking it?

Comment: Just set the header's `z-index' to 0 or lower than the x button. Or there would many solutions be.

Comment: If it was helpful then please select my answer :)

Comment: It was, now I have to make it responsive lol...

Comment: Have a nice journey of JS :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems `header` tag blocks the x button tag because `header` tag's `z-index` equal 1000. So when modal is opened I set `header`'s `z-index` to 0.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; 
}

body{
  animation-name: backgroundColorPalette;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: linear; 
}
html {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}

.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
     -khtml-user-select: none; 
       -moz-user-select: none; 
        -ms-user-select: none; 
            user-select: none; 
}
.bg {
  animation:slide 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, rgb(81, 128, 116) 50%, rgb(142, 100, 190) 50%);
  bottom:0;
  left:-50%;
  opacity:.5;
  position:fixed;
  right:-50%;
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
}

.bg2 {
  animation-direction:alternate-reverse;
  animation-duration:4s;
}

.bg3 {
  animation-duration:5s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform:translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateX(25%);
  }
}
header
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header .name
{
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 5em;
}


.showcase
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}
.showcase.active
{
  right: 300px;
}

.text
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text h2
{
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.text h3
{
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.text p
{
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  max-width: 700px;
}
.social
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
.social li a
{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2em;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #111;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.social li
{
  list-style: none;
}
.text a:hover
{
  letter-spacing: 6px;
}
.social li a:hover
{
  transform: scale(0.8) translateY(-15px);
}
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  
@media (max-width: 991px)
{
  .name h1{
    font-size: 6em;
  }

  .overlay {
    height: 5%;
  }

  .showcase,
  .showcase header
  {
    padding: 40px;
  }
  .text h2
  {
    font-size: 5em;
  }
  .text h3
  {
    font-size: 4em;
  }
  .text p
  {
    font-size: 3em;
  }  
  
  .social, 
  .social li, 
  .social li a
  {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 2px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bg"></div>
<div class="bg bg2"></div>
<div class="bg bg3"></div>
<!--
Delete this div tag
</div>

-->
  <section class="showcase">
    <header>
      <h1 class="name noselect">Some dude</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="text">
      <h2>Some dude</h2> 
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="social">
      <li ><a href="#" id="myBtn">About</a>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text in the Modal.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt commodi est deleniti cum distinctio minima dolore impedit eius, adipisci ea tenetur obcaecati iusto, dolorem, quaerat magni eaque rerum amet tempora!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    
    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    var header1 = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0];
    
    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      header1.style.zIndex = '0';
    }
    
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
      header1.style.zIndex = '1000';
    }
    
    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        
      header1.style.zIndex = '1000';
      }
    }
    </script>
</body>
<!--
delete this html tag
</html>

-->
```

Answer (score 1):

The header is overriding the span and the div. Put the header style "width" to "fit-content" works.

```
header
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```